# New Relic agent not reading NRIA_LICENSE_KEY environment value

Tags: newrelic

I am able to integrate my microservice written in Playframework(Java).
I had configured license key in the newrelic.yml file.

Now I want to externalize it by setting the value as an environment variable.
Found from the docs that I can do this by setting NRIA_LICENSE_KEY env variable.

So removed license key from yml file and now its looks like this :

```
license_key:
```

added env variable

```
NRIA_LICENSE_KEY= '123431234'
```

But I am getting below error :

```
Jun 27, 2018 12:03:24 +1000 [11360 1] com.newrelic INFO: Using default collector host: collector.newrelic.com
Jun 27, 2018 12:03:25 +1000 [11360 1] com.newrelic ERROR: license_key is empty in the config. Not starting New Relic Agent.
```

Just looking a way to set the value using env variable instead of putting it into yaml file as we don't want to check-in the license key in GIT.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I found the answer to my question.
I was using a wrong environment variable to set the license key.
I replace the variable NRIA_LICENSE_KEY with NEW_RELIC_LICENSE_KEY and it started working fine. This way, I don't have to save license as part of my code.